# Flux: Uncaught TypeError: store.off is not a function

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

While switching Button on the Website built with this mixin, it's creating Error and that is :   `Uncaught TypeError: store.off is not a function`

I have added View and store file with the post Below.The Error is occurring when I am pressing the buttons namely: "Register" & "Login".

But after Page Reload, It is working Fine.My SoreMixin File is Given below:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM *//**
     * mixin to let components listen to stores in a simple way
     * the component needs to implement `onStoreUpdate` to set the state
     * @param {Object} store
     * @param {String} [events="add remove reset change"]
     */
    module.exports = function(store, events) {
        if(!events) {
            events = "add remove reset change";
        }
        return {
            componentDidMount: function() {
                store.on(events, function() {
                    this.forceUpdate();
                }, this);
            },
            componentWillUnmount: function() {
                store.off(null, null, this);
            }
        };
    };
```

Store File:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var Dispatcher = require('project/shared/dispatcher');

var baseStore = {
    /**
     * backbone init method
     */
    initialize: function() {
        this.dispatchId = Dispatcher.register(this.handleDispatch.bind(this));
    },

    /**
     * handle the dispatcher actions
     * @param {Object} payload
     */
    handleDispatch: function(payload) { }
};

module.exports =
{
    BaseStore : baseStore,
    Model: Backbone.Model.extend(baseStore),
    Collection: Backbone.Collection.extend(baseStore)
};
```

View File:

```
    var React = require('react');
    var storeMixin = require('project/shared/helpers/storeMixin');
    var RouterStore = require('project/router/RouterStore');

    module.exports = React.createClass({
        mixins: [storeMixin(RouterStore)],
        RedirectRegister: function () {
            location.href = "#usersignup";
        },

        RedirectLogin: function () {
            location.href = "#userlogin";
        },
   render: function () {
           return (

    <div>
            <div >
            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Register" onClick={this.RedirectRegister}/>
            </div>

            <div>
            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Login" onClick={this.RedirectLogin}/>
            </div>



    </div>

            );
        }
    });
```

Comment: we would need your view code and your store code

Comment: @FrançoisRichard edited, added view code and store code there.

Comment: Solved Just Added: 

 if(store.hasOwnProperty('off')){
                store.off(null, null, this);
     }

Thanks @Richard for let me think in a different way

Comment: that's really weird to mix backbone model & store , it's like having model twice. Also does it mean you are fetching inside the stores ? cause this is an anti-pattern =/

Comment: Actually I am using FluxBone https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluxbone, For my current Project Architecture. It is lot Different From Flux and Backbone both. I am using Backbone Model and Collection For Backend api connection & React as a View and Flux's Dispatcher, Store for event Handling.

@Richard

Comment: I've read fluxbone and this is an antipattern, not good at all. It doesn't respect the flux pattern at all.

Comment: I am facing not a lot of Troubles while managing a big deal of CodeBase.

Comment: can You give an explanation  regarding your logic against fluxbone?@Richard

Comment: Look at this discussion here, the comments at the bottom of the page, I totally agree with deBrice explaination http://www.toptal.com/front-end/simple-data-flow-in-react-applications-using-flux-and-backbone

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no .off() function in your store that's why.

Read this example using eventEmiter https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#creating-stores

You'll use .on and removeListener (instead of .off())

Comment: Changed according to your Opinion and got this : 

"Uncaught TypeError: listener must be a function "
from 
events.js
@Richard

Comment: probably because you didn't write the listener properly, can't tell without the code

Comment: if you edit your code I could probably find out the problem

Comment: off and on methods are backbone events. The problem was Store.off() was receiving a value of undefined,so I had to check the object has his property or not by hasOwnProperty(). 
By adding this with my existing code, I have solved the problem, I think.
@Richard